# Can 2017 be written uniquely as a sum of 2 squares?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I know that $2017 = 9^2+44^2$, but how can I prove that this is the only possible way you can write 2017 as a sum of 2 squares?

Comment: if you are unfamiliar with advanced number theory topics such as Gaussian integers, then brute force checking is pretty much the only way to convince yourself.

Comment: observation by Euler, having more than one expression means the number is composite. Article by Brillhart, December 2009, A Note on Euler's Factoring Problem

Comment: It is quite quick to check in a spreadsheet.  Put the numbers from $0$ to $45$ in column A, then in column B write =sqrt(2017-A^2) and scan down for an integer.  Copy down is your friend.

Comment: While obviously not a proof, you can always quickly check wolframalpha, giving it the query 'solve x^2+y^2 over the integers'

Answer (score 8):

$2017$ is a prime number of the form $4k+1$, and for such a numbers it is well known that the decomposition as a sum of two squares is essentially unique.

The point is that the equality $2017=9^2+44^2$ can be translated in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ as $$2017 = (9+44i)(9-44i).$$

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a unique factorization domain, any other factorization of $2017$ coincides with the one above up to units. But the units of Gaussian integers are $\{\pm1, \, \pm i\}$, so the representation $2017= a^2+b^2$  is unique up to order and up to sign of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Wow, is that a theorem? If yes, does it have a proof?

Comment: It is Fermat theorem (first proven by Euler)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares

Comment: Ohhh... the Fermat theorem! Thanks so much, I nearly forgot about it.

Comment: @furfur Maybe not _the_ Fermat theorem. Perhaps just _a_ Fermat theorem.

Comment: And the reason $9+44i$ and $9-44i$ are irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is essentially because their square modulus is prime.